# Add values to a blank column from 2 other columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I want to create column C from column A and column B in my dataframe. I used append() but my column C does not pick values from one or the other of A and B for some reason. Can anyone help?

```
      A        B        C
0     Cat     "Blank"   Cat     
1     Mouse    Mouse    Mouse
2     Fish    "Blank"   Fish
3     "Blank" "Blank"   "Blank"
4     "Blank"  Dog      Dog
```

Comment: here 'Blank' is string or placeholder of `NaN`?

Comment: What do you want in your column C ?

Comment: I see question is not complete, you need to explain it explicitly to seek and answer, you need to show us how you are approaching which is not giving desired results?

Comment: Blank is NaN. Column C starts with being blank and needs to pick value from column A but if column A is blank then column B. If both are blank then column C will be blank too. In the df above I have shown what the final C should look like after picking values from A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`combine first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)

```
df['C'] = df.A.combine_first(df.B)
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
      A      B      C
0    Cat    NaN    Cat
1  Mouse  Mouse  Mouse
2   Fish    NaN   Fish
3    NaN    NaN    NaN
4    NaN    Dog    Dog
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function(column_A, column_B):
    if column_A != 'Blank':
        return(column_A)
    elif column_B != 'Blank':
        return(column_B)
    else :
        return('Blank')

df["C"] = df.apply(lambda r : function(r.A,r.B),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `bfill` to copy value from B to A only if A is `NaN`:

```
df['C'] = df[['A', 'B']].bfill(axis=1)['A']
```

```
>>> df
       A      B      C
0    Cat    NaN    Cat
1  Mouse  Mouse  Mouse
2   Fish    NaN   Fish
3    NaN    NaN    NaN
4    NaN    Dog    Dog
```